# My React Native App Crash After Update Target Sdk Version 31

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, react-native-reanimated

My React Native App crashes after updating the target Sdk version and compileSdkVersion 31. It was working version 30. Google Play forced us to this update. The app crashes on Android 12 version devices. It works on Android 10 or 11.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^0.12.2",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.9",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.6",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "7.8.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.4",
    "react-native-animated-pagination-dots": "^0.1.72",
    "react-native-autoheight-webview": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1263.0",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.3.7",
    "react-native-directory-picker": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "3.2.1",
    "react-native-immersive-bars": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-month-year-picker": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.2.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^14.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.61.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hamza did you find the solution?

Comment: yes. adding implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' to build.gradle was solution for me

Comment: What was the error in the logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add this line inside your dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
}
```

Maybe is that problem here:
[Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894168/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag/71794586#71794586)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem 2 days ago.
You have to do these changes:

file: android/build.gradle

> Change these versions like these:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
}
```

file: android/app/build.gradle

> Add `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'` dependency.

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
...
}
```

**EDIT:** As of late 2022, version 2.7.1 worked, a few other answers suggest using 2.6.0 too which you may try if they work with your system or not.

```
`implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'`
```

file: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

> Add `android:exported="true"` to the main activity.

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:exported="true"
  ...
 >
```

**Also you need to add `android:exported="false"`** to each XML tag that has an `intent-filter` like services and others.

For example, this is my notification service that has an `intent-filter` as its child:

```
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**EDIT:** Besides this make sure you are using JDK 11

**EDIT:** Also if the problem persists delete .gradle folder inside the android folder.

Comment: Thankyou for explaining and I tried your solution and now my app works fine.

Comment: > Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

Comment: How do we know which JDK version we're using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you also increase your buildToolsVersion to "31.0.0"

Please also make sure that it uses Java 11 and not Java 8.

Comment: it was not work

Comment: Can you post what error it shows

Comment: no error is displayed. the app crashes directly

Comment: Please check the logs in Android studio logcat. It will definitely show you the crash error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71029845/11070863

Answer (score 0):

The only one solution that worked for me was **to remove/comment out** `Flipper`.
Here is how to do that:
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1326#issuecomment-653470251

Comment: I think this solution is more like a workaround rather than a fix. I don't use Flipper at all, that's why this solution worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

Dude. Have you tried to update other libraries?

I had same issue and upgrading firebase library version was the solution.

This might be not helpful.

I hope you will fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).