# React native App crashing [ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1 Process: com.************, PID: 9629 ] after updating compileSdkVersion to 31

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, crash

I am trying to update one of my old project in which our build.gradle file was like this

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        androidXCore = "1.7.0" 
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     google()
     jcenter()
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
allprojects {
     configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

But as per google play console suggested
compileSdkVersion should be 31
targetSdkVersion should be 31

when I tried to update it React native app shows build successful and when I try to run that App crashes and after inspecting it through Android studio LogCat I get this Fatal error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1 Process: com.myimportantprojectabc, PID: 9629
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.myimportantprojectabc: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)
requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:285)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:158)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:185)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:103)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

My React Native version is "react-native": "^0.66.5",

**After Updating build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        androidXCore = "1.7.0" 
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     google()
     jcenter()
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
allprojects {
     configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
          }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549190/13884276

file: android/app/build.gradle

Add implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' dependency.

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
...
}
```

file: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Add android:exported="true" to the main activity.

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:exported="true"
  ...
 >
```